# regex | extract numbers preceded by defined strings

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have strings like:

```
Bla bla 0.75 oz. Bottle
Mugs, 8oz. White
Bowls, 4.4" dia x 2.5", 12ml. Natural
Ala bala 3.3" 30ml Bottle'
```

I want to extract the numeric value which occurs before my pre-defined lookaheads, in this case `[oz, ml]`

```
0.75 oz
8 oz
12 ml
30 ml
```

I have the below code:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
look_ahead = "oz|ml"

s = pd.Series(['Bla bla 0.75 oz. Bottle',
              'Mugs, 8oz. White',
              'Bowls, 4.4" dia x 2.5", 12ml. Natural',
              'Ala bala 3.3" 30ml Bottle'])
size_and_units = s.str.findall(
        rf"((?!,)[0-9]+.*[0-9]* *(?={look_ahead})[a-zA-Z]+)")

print(size_and_units)
```

Which outputs this:

```
0                  [0.75 oz]
1                      [8oz]
2    [4.4" dia x 2.5", 12ml]
3                [3.3" 30ml]
```

You can see there is a mismatch between what I want as output and what I am getting from my script. I think my regex code is picking everything between first numeric value and my defined lookahead, however I only want the last numeric value before my lookahead.

I am out of my depth for regex. Can someone help fix this.
Thank you!

Comment: In `[0-9]+.*[0-9]*`, replace `.` with `\.`. `.` means _any character_. `\.` means a period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making as few changes to your regex, so you know what you did wrong:
in `[0-9]+.*[0-9]*`, replace `.` with `\.`. `.` means *any character*. `\.` means a period.

```
s = pd.Series(['Bla bla 0.75 oz. Bottle',
              'Mugs, 8oz. White',
              'Bowls, 4.4" dia x 2.5", 12ml. Natural',
              'Ala bala 3.3" 30ml Bottle'])
size_and_units = s.str.findall(
        rf"((?!,)[0-9]+\.*[0-9]* *(?={look_ahead})[a-zA-Z]+)")
```

gives:

```
0    [0.75 oz]
1        [8oz]
2       [12ml]
3       [30ml]
```

You don't need to use a lookahead at all though, since you also want to match the units. Just do

```
\d+\.*\d*\s*(?:oz|ml)
```

This gives the same result:

```
size_and_units = s.str.findall(
        rf"\d+\.*\d*\s*(?:{look_ahead})")
```

Answer (score 1):

Some notes about the pattern that you tried:

- You can omit the lookahead `(?!,)` as it is always true because you start the next match for a digit
- In this part `.*[0-9]* *(?=oz|ml)[a-zA-Z]+)` this is all optional `.*[0-9]* *` and will match until the end of the string. Then it will backtrack till it can match either `oz` or `ml` and will match 1 or more chars a-zA-Z so it could also match `0.75 ozaaaaaaa`

If you want the matches, you don't need a capture group or lookarounds. You can match:

```
\b\d+(?:\.\d+)*\s*(?:oz|ml)\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)*` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `\s*(?:oz|ml)` Match optional whitespace chars and either `oz` or `ml`
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/26tG0L/1)

```
import pandas as pd

look_ahead = "oz|ml"

s = pd.Series(['Bla bla 0.75 oz. Bottle',
               'Mugs, 8oz. White',
               'Bowls, 4.4" dia x 2.5", 12ml. Natural',
               'Ala bala 3.3" 30ml Bottle'])
size_and_units = s.str.findall(
    rf"\b\d+(?:\.\d+)*\s*(?:{look_ahead})\b")

print(size_and_units)
```

Output

```
0    [0.75 oz]
1        [8oz]
2       [12ml]
3       [30ml]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that regex expression will work for you.

```
[0-9]+\.*[0-9]* *(oz|ml)
```